# Calculating sum $\sum_{i=k}^{n}i\binom{i}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I can see that the sum $\sum_{i=k}^{n}i\binom{i}{k}$ is very similar to the hockey-stick identity ($\sum_{i=k}^{n}\binom{i}{k} =\binom{n+1}{k+1}$) which I managed to calculate using Pascal's identity:$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$ but I can't manage to solve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [WolframAlpha to the rescue?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+i*%28i+choose+k%29%2C+i+from+k+to+n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=k}^n i\binom{i}{k}
&= \sum_{i=k}^n (i+1-1)\binom{i}{k} \\
&= (k+1)\sum_{i=k}^n \frac{i+1}{k+1}\binom{i}{k} - \sum_{i=k}^n\binom{i}{k} \\
&= (k+1)\sum_{i=k}^n \binom{i+1}{k+1} - \binom{n+1}{k+1} \\
&= (k+1)\binom{n+2}{k+2} - \binom{n+1}{k+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped me a lot.